# Реально ли полностью отказаться от употребления иностранный слов?

Tags: иностранные-слова

Депутаты предложили ввести штрафы за употребление иностранных слов.
Как вы думаете, реально ли это? Конечно, бесконечные "электораты" с "кворумами" надоели, но тогда ведь придется исключить из русского языка вообще две трети слов.
А еще интересно: только ли русский язык так сильно засорен иностранными словами? А как насчет других языков, того же английского (не американского)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Депутаты предложили ввести штрафы за употребление иностранных слов, если есть русские аналоги, а говорящий — журналист или, например, депутат. По крайней мере, такие выводы я сделал, смотря выступление Жириновского по Пятому каналу.

В английском очень много (по некоторым источника — до 70%) лексики из латинского языка. Другое дело, что я, например, не считаю, что обрусевшее слово, являющееся частью русского языка уже несколько сотен лет, может быть "иностранным".

Answer (score 2):

Что
 ж - sed lex, duro lex, начнем подбирать синонимы иностранным словам:

Президент - правитель.
Премьер-министр - старший боярин. 
Спикер - ведущий. 
Парламент, сенат - Земский собор.
Губернатор - удельный правитель.
Конституция - Русская правда.
Кодекс - уложение.  
Полицейский - городовой.  
Прокурор - обвинитель.  
Адвокат - защитник.  
Сержант - десятник.  
Лейтенант - сотник.
Император - главнокомадующий.
Библия - Книги.

И еще много других слов, имеющих аналоги (**заменители!**) в русском 
языке. Благо хоть строгость российских законов компенсируется их 
повальным неисполнением.

Comment: Dura.)))) Lex женского рода, поэтому "дура".
А спикер (англ. speak) - "говорун"(отличающийся умом и сообразительностью); парламент - "говорильня" (от ит. parlare)... то ли дело у нас - Дума! И Русская правда вместо Конституция тоже неплохо звучит.

Comment: Мне очень нравится замена премьер-министру)

Comment: >Президент - правитель.

Слово *president* можно дословно перевести как *председатель*. Тот, кто сидит впереди. И то и другое слово от праиндоевропейского корня *sed-

Comment: @Nikolja, я имею в виду не кальку с заимствованного слова, а русский аналог заимствования. Для президента таковыми словами будут как раз "правитель", "государь". Председатель в современных реалиях это скорее спикер парламента.

Answer (score 2):

Самое смешное в этой цепочке  - это то, что закон придумали депутаты, а не лингвисты. Это то же самое самое, если лингвисты оставят свою работу и будут писать законы, вмешиваться в политику. Кстати, лингвисты не одобрили этот закон, что вполне естественно.

И все равно, как бы депутаты ни пытались очистить русский язык от иностранных слов , им это не удастся.То что нужно языку - останется, а то лишнее, уйдет само по себе. 
Известный ревнитель русского языка Адмирал Шишков тоже некогда пытался очистить русский от "мусора". Так, он пытался заменить слово "галоши" на "мокроступы".Слово, как видим, не прижилось.

Мокроступы - не лыжи, а галоши. Можете почитать в Википедии.

Именно мОкруступы. Вы правы.

Comment: >Так, он пытался заменить слово "галоши" на "макроступы".

Кажется "мокроступы".

Comment: *Макроступы* - это лыжи.

Answer (score 2):

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК

Прежде всего, надо разобраться, какие слова мы считаем иностранными. С точки зрения происхождения в русском языке выделяется исконно русская и заимствованная лексика. В свою очередь, в исконно русской лексике можно выделить следующие пласты:1) индоевропейский; 2) общеславянский; 3) восточнославянский (древнерусский); 4) собственно русский.

Собственно русская лексика - это слова, возникшие с момента образования русской народности (с XIV в.) и рождающиеся в языке и в настоящее время (они отсутствуют в укр. и белорус. языках). Для слов этого разряда характерно наличие в их составе словообразовательных элементов, специфичных для русского языка.

Языки контактирующих народов  испытывают взаимное влияние,  вследствие чего происходит заимствование иноязычных слов. Заимствование обогащает язык, делает его более гибким и обычно не ущемляет его, так как при этом сохраняется основной словарь языка и его грамматический строй.

Причины иноязычного заимствования могут    быть внешними и внутренними. 
Внешние причины - это обозначение с помощью иноязычного слова новых или измененных предметов, понятий, терминов: портье (коридорный), трансформатор (преобразователь) , также: плюрализм, приватизация и др. Внутриязыковые причины – это тенденция в специализации значений слов, при этом  русское слов может расщепляться на два, например: рассказ – репортаж, всеобщий – тотальный, местный – локальный. Это уже близкие по смыслу, но не синонимичные пары.

Таким образом, разобраться в языковых тонкостях депутатам, конечно, не под силу, но они это уже осознали и закон не приняли. Тем не менее проблема существует, и ее можно описать примерно так.

Заимствованные слова – почему бы и нет! Они делают нашу лексику богаче, разнообразнее. Единственное условие - заимствования должны органично вписываться в языковую среду, не подавлять исконную речь своим количеством и не приводить к взаимному непониманию при общении.

Вот например. Вы хотите изменить свою жизнь? Тогда станьте креативным человеком, отметив это качество в своем резюме. Не забывайте о дресс-коде - на работе, да и вообще в различных ситуациях. Модный тренд этого  года - монохромные решения. Теперь вам прямой путь в хедлайнеры. Вы не знаете, что это такое? Это просто раскрученные бренды – да нет, не торговые марки, это я в переносном смысле.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 08.07.14

Когда-то всё то уже было.Был Шишков с его «Рассуждением о старом и новом слоге», было противостояние западников и славянофилов. И всё-таки великая русская литература 19 века написана слогом Карамзина и Пушкина, и не говорим мы "рубня" вместо "сабля" или "тыкня" вместо "пика".  Вот и Пушкин писал: «…Но панталоны, фрак, жилет, Всех этих слов на русском нет».

Наш великий поэт был патриотом, но при этом считал, что народность совсем не предполагает замкнутости от чужих влияний, обособленности национальной культуры. Ошибочна постановка вопроса: либо преданность своему, исконному, родному, либо доступность чужим влияниям. Потребность к обогащению извне – это не признак слабости, а напротив, признак силы и жизненности как народа, так и языка.  «Субстанция народного духа, как все живое, питается заимствованным извне материалом, который она перерабатывает и усваивает, не теряя от этого, а, напротив, развивая этим свое национальное своеобразие».

Русский язык – великий, сильный, могучий.  Из других языков он возьмет только самое лучшее и достойное, чтобы стать еще сильнее и самобытнее. Сильному не нужна защита, он защит себя сам. Каждый из нас – носитель этого языка.  Стремитесь сделать свою речь правильной, выразительной, грамотной и используйте в ней только те новые слова, которые  делают язык богаче, но никак не превращают его в непонятное наречие.

Comment: @София, извините, но последние два абзаца - это демагогия. Без работы русистов по СЛОВООБРАЗОВАНИЮ у нас просто не будет русских неологизмов, и русские слова будут вытеснены американизмами. То, что язык НЕОБХОДИМО защищать, это поняли не только французы, но и бОльшая половина человечества, если посчитаете численность тех народов, которые защищают свои языки.Ваши аргументы-это доводы русистов, которые НЕ ЗНАЮТ других языков и выводят "законы", основываясь ТОЛЬКО на плебейской практике русского языка. Обогащение извне-это именно слабость!Это Вам скажет араб, китаец, еврей и ещё десятки народов.

Comment: А вот один из  создателей русского литературного языка А.С. Пушкин не разделял мнение арабов, китайцев и др. Он писал: "Язык славянорусский имеет неоспоримые превосходства пред всеми европейскими: судьба его была чрезвычайно счастлива. В XI веке древнегреческий язык  открыл ему свой лексикон — сокровищницу гармонии, даровав ему законы обдуманной своей грамматики, свои прекрасные обороты, величественное течение речи; словом, усыновил его, избавя таким образом от медленных усовершенствований времени. Сам по себе уже звучный и выразительный, отселе заимствует он гибкость и правильность".

Comment: Это тоже, по-вашему, демагогия? Когда заимствованное слово фиксируется в словарях, оно получает "гражданство": определяется его род, склонение, сочетаемость, от него  образуются новые слова по законам русской грамматики.

Comment: "Паркинг" в отличие от "парковки", "инжиниринг" в отличие от "инженерии", "тренинг" в отличие от "тренировки" - это все по законам "русской" грамматики??? :-)

Comment: У "кофе" удалось определить род, или ещё в процессе? :-)

Comment: @София Вы прикрываетесь за авторитеты, которые выражали СВОЁ частное мнение. Противоположных мнений было в сотни раз больше. Посмотрите, что пишет Тургенев и другие классики по этому поводу. Кстати и сам Пушкин не был АПОЛОГЕТОМ заимствований! (Вы вырвали просто удобный кусок). Разве Пушкин вводил в русский язык францизмы, владея этим языком в совершенстве? Ровно так, как это делают сейчас КАЖДЫЙ ДЕНЬ полуграмотные радио- и телеведущие.

Comment: @София Потом Пушкин не знал, что настанет информационная эра, когда прозвучавшее раз слово в Москве будет тут же сто раз повторено на Камчатке. И он не знал, что народ великого языка и культуры упадет на столько, что превратиться в американских культурологических лизоблюдов, смотрящих им в рот, и обезьянничая перед ними. Будет называть населенные пункты под Москвой "Хиллс"-ами, "вилладжами", свои дома "коттеджами" ("хибарами", по-английски), подражая мурлыкать дебиловатое "вау". Разве вы не видите во ЧТО превращается русский народ???

Comment: @София А потом, КЕМ фиксируется в словарях? Такими же чинушами от языка, как и Вы? (Если вы из этого цеха, извините, если я ошибаюсь.) Что-то в английских, французских, арабских, китайских и ВСЕХ ОСТАЛЬНЫХ(за исключением языков СССР) не фиксировались русские слова! Пресловутый "спутник" использовался только год, пока не полетел американский, и с того момента никто не знает этого слова. Что-то не вошло в английский и китайский "космонавт". Наше изобретенные "радио" и "телевидение/телевижин" - не русские слова, поэтому и вошли. ТОЛЬКО МЫ уничтожае родной язык, а американцы смеются над вами.

Comment: @София посмотрите. Это про нас - русских обезьян или попугаев http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=srrTPMjRRsU

   (прямо сейчас)

Comment: ПАРК - полезное многозначное слово англ. происхождения. ПАРКОВАТЬ - Ставить автомобиль на стоянку (образовано на русской почве с помощью суффикса ОВА). ПАРКОВКА и СТОЯНКА - это (1) действие, (2) территория. СТОЯНКА - слово многозначное: "стоянка один час", "стоянка первобытного человека", "устроили тут стоянку, стоянка запрещена". ПАРКОВКА - это конкретнее и относится к колесному транспорту. А ПАРКИНГ им не конкурент, это многоэтажная, многоместная парковка/стоянка. Получается , что слова всякие нужны и слова всякие важны. Язы сам разберется, руководить им не надо.

Answer (score 1):

Своей фантазией и непосредственностью депутаты подчас напоминают детей. Наивность некоторых шедевров законотворчества можно оправдать только искренностью порывов их патриотических чувств и отеческой заботой об избирателях.

Что же до реальной выполнимости подобных законов, то вспоминается классика: "Ксанф, выпей море!"

Comment: Конечно, им там скучно, вот они и развлекаются.

Answer (score 1):

Я была бы очень рада, если в русском перестали бы использовать, или хотя бы уменьшили количество явно не обрусевших иностранных (в частности английских) слов. Но, говоря это, исключить все слова, пришедшие из вне, просто невозможно. Как Вы сами сказали, придётся исключить ту треть которая пришла из греческого, и ту, что пришла из французского, и ещё щепотку из остальных. Как же тогда приминать душ или лежать в ванной? :) Но подчистить тот языковой мусор, который накопился на поверхности, я совсем не против и очень даже за.

Comment: >Как же тогда приминать душ или лежать в ванной? :)

У поляков вместо немецкого слова "душ" употребляется слово "прышник". А у болгар *ванна* может называться "баня". Как в мультике про домового Кузю. :-)

Так что, как вариант, *вспрыснуться в баньке*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Отказаться - реально, это доказал опыт французов, арабов, евреев, китайцев, японцев, индийцев, корейцев, да почти всех народов Юго-Восточной Азии.
2. Именно крупными штрафами (до 20 тыс. евро) французы добились чистоты и уважения к родному языку. Так что это «РЕАЛЬНО», выражаясь Вашей американо-пацанской лексикой.
3. Исключить необходимо не 2/3, а только пару-тройку сотен американизмов, внедренных в русский язык за последние 15-20 лет. Откройте русскую классику – там чистый русский язык, при этом современному читателю всё понятно. Не заметно, чтобы Гоголю или Пушкину, да и Шукшину было затруднительно передавать чувства, описания и мысли без нынешний «трендов-брендов» и прочего американского мусора. Неумение говорить или писать на русском языке без американизмов – это не проблема языка, а проблема говорящего (по-Вашему – «спикера»).
4. Из рабочих языков ООН только русских не принимает меры к защите и активно засоряется, точнее – перерождается. Сравнение заимствований в английском с нынешней ситуацией по уничтожению русского языка (превращению его в американский суржик) не оправданно. Заимствования в английском языке произошли на момент становления, формирования английского языка, и теперь они представляют только исторический интерес. Сейчас английский язык почти не заимствует, так как это ещё и элемент культурного суверенитета, а обогащается за счет жаргонизмов и диалектов. Что и мы могли бы делать вместо американизмов. Русский же язык, сформированный и состоявшийся как язык величайшей мировой литературы, СЕЙЧАС претерпевает процесс дегенерации. Если так пойдет, через 10 лет он станет языком германской группы, и называться «русским» не будет иметь право.
5. Не лингвисты против этого закона. По всем опросам, 70 процентов россиян, включая филологов, переводчиков, журналистов, писателей, по ВСЕЙ России, а не только Москвы, ЗА принятие данного закона! Все фракции проголосовали ЗА закон, только "Едро" по указке Администрации президента завалило законопроект. Это очередная победа чиновников, а не демократии.

Comment: @София Именно - КОНКУРЕНТ! "Паркинг" - это просто замена слова "парковка". Ещё 5 лет назад было словосочетание "многоэтажная парковка". А почему тогда на эвакуаторах уже пишут "паркинг"? При чем тут многоэтажный? Почему старые таблички с "парковкой" тупо меняют на "паркинг"? По Вашей логике надо придумать отдельные слова для: подземной парковки, надземной, платной, бесплатной, грузовой, легковой. Все слова нужны? Ну тогда перепишите весь английский словарь в русский. Тогда и матерные слова "нужны"! Язык сам НЕ разберется, если его носители духовные уроды. Поэтому языки УЖЕ регулируются.

Comment: @София Вы слепо обслуживаете своё заблуждение, вдолбленное Вам в голову русистами советского периода, типа Щербины, которые понятия не имели о процессах в других языках. Эти мантры - "все живые языки развиваются путем заимствования" не выдерживают критики, как только вы дадите себе труд поучить иностранный язык. Посмотрите в скольких языках слова "компьютер", "глобализация" и проч.амер.мусор русского языка звучит не по-английски. По Вашему, ТОЛЬКО для русского языка работают выдуманные Вами правила? Но только русский язык вырождается, а не французский, арабский, китайский и ещё сотни языков.

Comment: @София Мне не понятно, зачем такие люди как Вы, которые, по призванию, должны любить русский язык (если Вы его ненавидите, тогда нет дискуссии) делаете из себя вид слепых или слабоумных. Зачем Вы просто тупо твердите заклинания, которые НЕ ИМЕЮТ НИЧЕГО ОБЩЕГО С ЖИЗНЬЮ??Русский язык уже потерял тысячи красивейших слов. Американизация языка - это ещё и примитивизация, а не обогащение, это подмена и лукавство смыслов. Сколько прекрасных и точных слов убили фотографические термины "позитивно"/"негативно"!Что такое "коррупция","нелегитимный","киллер"?Это заменители честных, обличающих русских слов

Comment: Гусляр, а зачем так много чувств?. Здесь люди просто высказывают свое мнение и стараются терпимо относиться к мнению других. Форум - это не то место, где Вы можете приложить свою кипучую энергию. И лексику здесь лучше применять не экспрессивную, Вы же не на митинге. Думаю, Вам полезнее общаться с людьми, которые изначально разделяют Ваши взгляды, тогда вы вместе можете подумать и обсудить, какие конструктивные меры следует принять для защиты языка. А дальше действовать в соответствии с вашими планами и обращаться в структуры, которые реально могут повлиять на ситуацию.

Comment: @София Спасибо большое за совет и понимание!Вы всё правильно пишите. Проблема в том, что мои единомышленники - это русские, живущие за рубежом, и иностранцы, владеющие русским. Согласитесь - не велика кучка. А российские "русисты" и журналисты во главе с кандидатом химических наук Эммой Володарской, которая всю жизнь посвятила "влиянию английского языка на русский" с пеной у рта, с подтасовкой фактов, с откровенным враньем отстаивают уничтожение русского языка.Ну разве не честнее было бы им перейти на английский, как это делала русская элита 19 века с французским, и оставить нам русский язык?

Comment: @София Извините за экспрессию - я не догадался, что Вы просто подзуживаете. :-)